# Custom Bootstrapped Standard Error: numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Tags: r, save, simulation, glm, statistics-bootstrap

I am writing a custom script to bootstrap standard errors in a GLM in R and receive the following error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? My code:

```
#Number of simulations
sims<-numbersimsdesired

#Set up place to store data
saved.se<-matrix(NA,sims,numberofcolumnsdesired)
y<-matrix(NA,realdata.rownumber)
x1<-matrix(NA,realdata.rownumber)
x2<-matrix(NA,realdata.rownumber)

#Resample entire dataset with replacement
for (sim in 1:sims) {
    fake.data<-sample(1:nrow(data5),nrow(data5),replace=TRUE)

    #Define variables for GLM using fake data
    y<-realdata$y[fake.data]
    x1<-realdata$x1[fake.data]
    x2<-realdata$x2[fake.data]

    #Run GLM on fake data, extract SEs, save SE into matrix
    glm.output<-glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = "poisson", data = fake.data)  
    saved.se[sim,]<-summary(glm.output)$coefficients[0,2]
    }
```

An example: if we suppose sims = 1000 and we want 10 columns (suppose instead of x1 and x2, we have x1...x10) the goal is a dataset with 1,000 rows and 10 columns containing each explanatory variable's SEs.

Comment: 1) Why don't you use package boot? 2) How is `fake.data` defined?

Comment: Also, indexing is starts with 1 in R, not with 0.

Comment: @Roland (1) The project I am working on is intended to NOT use boot().  Would be great if I could but I am supposed to create this from scratch.  (2) I fixed fake.data to be the name of the sampled dataset as I originally intended.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: There are numerous errors/misconceptions in your code. I've added an alternative that doesn't use `boot` to my answer.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand the error behind that cryptic message though, it helps develop debugging skills.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a reason to reinvent the wheel. Here is an example of bootstrapping the standard error of the intercept with the boot package:

```
set.seed(42)
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
x1 <- 1:9
x2 <- sample(9)
DF <- data.frame(counts, x1, x2)
glm1 <- glm(counts ~ x1 + x2, family = poisson(), data=DF)
summary(glm1)$coef

#              Estimate Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept) 2.08416378 0.42561333 4.896848 9.738611e-07
#x1          0.04838210 0.04370521 1.107010 2.682897e-01
#x2          0.09418791 0.04446747 2.118131 3.416400e-02

library(boot)

intercept.se <- function(d, i) {
  glm1.b <- glm(counts ~ x1 + x2, family = poisson(), data=d[i,])
  summary(glm1.b)$coef[1,2]
}

set.seed(42)
boot.intercept.se <- boot(DF, intercept.se, R=999)

#ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#
#
#Call:
#boot(data = DF, statistic = intercept.se, R = 999)
#
#
#Bootstrap Statistics :
#     original     bias  std. error
#t1* 0.4256133 0.103114   0.2994377
```

**Edit:**

If you prefer doing it without a package:

```
n <- 999
set.seed(42)
ind <- matrix(sample(nrow(DF), nrow(DF)*n, replace=TRUE), nrow=n)
boot.values <- apply(ind, 1, function(...) {
  i <- c(...)
  intercept.se(DF, i)
})

sd(boot.values)
#[1] 0.2994377
```